# Не отображается шрифт подключенный через CSS (@font-face) при локальном открытии файла

Tags: html, css, шрифты

помогите решить проблему отображения шрифтов.

Файлы шрифта лежат по пути папка-проекта\fonts\Roboto\RobotoLight
В корне каталога лежит файл fonts.css рядом с основным css файлом. В нем описывается @font-face следующим образом:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "RobotoLight";
src: url("/fonts/Roboto/RobotoLight/RobotoLight.eot");
src: url("/fonts/Roboto/RobotoLight/RobotoLight.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("/fonts/Roboto/RobotoLight/RobotoLight.woff") format("woff"),
url("/fonts/Roboto/RobotoLight/RobotoLight.ttf") format("truetype");
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

В основном файле CSS прописывается `font-family: RobotoLight;` для элемента которому необходимо задать данный шрифт.

В итоге при запуске html файла локально (file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/project/index.html)
Шрифты не отображаются! Отображается стандартный шрифт по умолчанию, не смотря на то, что в DevTools показан шрифт RobotoLight.

Однако при запуске на localhost (локальном сервере) шрифт отображается.

В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить? Спасибо большое!

Comment: При локальном открытии файла в консоли так же высвечивается данная ошибка 

`GET file:///C:/fonts/Roboto/RobotoLight/RobotoLight.woff net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Однако данный файл по данному пути лежит в папке

Comment: А вы подключили fonts.css к основному css через @import или подключили fonts.css в index.html перед основным файлом css?

Comment: Или же что-бы не париться и не подключать лишний фаил просто скопируйте всё с fonts.css и вставьте в самом начале основного файла css

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте шрифты в формате `.otf`. Их можно найти на [сайте Google Fonts](http://fonts.google.com).